# View more marker when mouse over on the marker group

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

[image]

while loading map, application will display the balloon marker like Group-a, When i click the Group-A marker, then marker get expand will display like Group-B.

Can please advise how to create marker balloon like attached screen shot.

in site they implemented the below image like sample here
[Sample MAP](http://www.ejw.de/ejw-vor-ort/)

please tell me how to implement below markup in google maps.

Comment: I would advise to use MarkerClusterer. You can find it [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries).

Comment: There no demo sample as per above attached screen.

Comment: It is **Overlapping** **Marker** **Spiderfier** **for** **google** **Maps** **3** -> https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier that is in use in the example above.

Comment: Thanks to @davidkonrad                                            will try this Overlapping Marker Spiderfie and come back with doubt

Comment: I know it's not the one in the screenshot. I would be interested to see the loading time for both solutions compared. I had pretty good results with Marker Clusterer Plus.